# AWS run etl scheduled script on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks

I have some etl python scripts on an EC2 instance which I run in order to fetch, process and load some data in a Postgresql DB that is hosted on the same EC2 instance.

The request was to host the DB on the EC2 instance instead of using RDS in order to save money.

The scripts take 1 hour to complete (because of some heavy processing involved which consumes 90% of the time).

I would like to build a solution to automate this task.

What I would like to do is to:

1. Turn on the EC2 instance at a given time;
2. Run the scripts inside the EC2 instance;
3. Turn off the EC2 instance after the scripts finish their job (which means after 1 hour);

I've seen some solutions with AWS System Manager and AWS Lambda, but they all seem outdated since the AWS interface changed.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-eventbridge/) which uses the [EventBridge scheduled events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) coupled with Lambda.

Comment: This might help: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)